# MySql Query for Login not working

Tags: php, mysql

I developed a login form to use for logging in, but when I try to login it does not get through. Below is part of the code that I used. The part that has `$num = mysql_num_rows()` returns a zero when I echo `$num`. Why is it like that? It seems my `INSERT` query is not returning results. Please help.

```
if ($warning==''){  
        $query="SELECT first_name FROM tblusers WHERE (email='$username') AND (password='".md5($_POST['password'])."')";
        $result=@mysql_query($query);
        $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
        @mysql_close();
        echo $num."perfecto".$result;           
        if($num==1)
        {
            $u=new User($username);
            include ('includes/highlight.inc.php');
            //insert user into session
            if ($username=='admin'){
                $_SESSION['user']=$username;
                $p=new Page('Log In'.$username);
                $p->setHeading('Welcome '.$u->getFirstName());
                $p->setContent($cont."<br/><br/><br/> Use the administrator's panel on the right to do the administration work of the 
                                website. To block and unblock users you use the <font color=red><b>View Auctions</b></font> link, and 
                                that is when you can block the user after assessing their record.");
                $p->printIt();
            } else {
            $_SESSION['user']=$username;
            $p=new Page('Log In'.$username);
            $p->setHeading('Welcome '.$u->getFirstName());
            $p->setContent($cont."<br/><br/><br/>".$text);
            $p->printIt(); }

        }
```

Comment: Check manual the query

Comment: can you try this : SELECT first_name FROM tblusers WHERE email='$username' AND password='md5($_POST['password'])' as the query

Comment: Do a `var_dump($query);` below your `SELECT`-line and compare the containing variables with the values in your database. Other than that (not related to your question, the mysql extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: where does $username come from? also MD5 doesn't make for a secure anything anymore.

Answer (score 0):

change your query string to :

```
$query="SELECT first_name FROM tblusers WHERE email='".$username."' AND password='".md5($_POST['password'])."'";
```

and also check the query string using `echo $query` to make sure it's correct

Answer (score 0):

Change your query string as below:

```
$password = md5($_POST['password']);
$query = "SELECT first_name FROM tblusers WHERE email='".$username."' AND password = '".$password."'";
```

Hope this may help you.

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem is that MD5 resulted into different results for the same password, so I couldn't login. It works if the password is not decrypted. I don't know what to use because even sha1 refused to work